# Can't get iPad mini into recovery mode

Tags: ipad, restore

Good day,

After several failed attempts, my iPad Mini is locked and the error `iPad is disabled - Try again in 13,568` is appearing.

Now, I do not have anything important on the device and I am totally okay if I lose everything in there.

However, I am not able to get it to work in recovery mode using the following technique

- turn the device off.
- open itunes
- hold home button for couple of seconds.
- insert the USB cable

After doing this steps, the device boots normally and gets stuck on the `disabled` page again.

What can I do to bypass this?

Comment: Try again in 13,568?

Comment: @JohnRamos probably the best answer.

Comment: Have you tried the steps here? https://support.apple.com/en-ca/ht204306

Answer (score 1):

If you try too many times to login with the wrong passoword, iOS will force you to wait longer and longer after each failed attempt. Your ipad is telling you that you now must wait 13,568 minutes before you can attempt another login.

If you have a beckup in itunes, you can plug the ipad into your laptop and Restore from Backup in iTunes. However, you will still need the correct password to login after restore.

If this does not work, your only options are to wipe the iPad and start over as if new.

You can plug in the iPad into iTunes, and hold down power and home buttons until you get a screen prompting you to plug in your iPad into iTunes. You should get a dialog box asking if you wish to Restore or Update, and you should select Restore.
You can also log into icloud.com and force a remote wipe on your iPad.

For details, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Turn on the iPad.
Now hold both the home button and lock/power button. Keep holding the buttons until it is in recovery mode. You needs to hold it for about 10 seconds or so. After iTunes logo appear you can update or restore the iPad.